# python pip config file - custom scripts and library installation paths

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip

I am trying to get pip to respect some configurations, such as location of the scripts and library location. So, every time I install using pip at the moment, I do something like:

```
pip install --install-option="--install-scripts=/home/xx/bin" --install-option="--install-lib=/home/xx/lib/python2.7" packagename
```

which is fine, but rather long, and when I have a requirements file it becomes a pain. I was wondering if anyone know where I can put the `--install-option="--install-scripts=/home/xx/bin" --install-option="--install-lib=/home/xx/lib/python2.7"` so that everytime I run:

```
pip install package
```

..it respects my install scripts and install options.

Id appreciate if anyone has suggestions for this - I did look at the [docs](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/configuration.html) but it does not seem to help.

Thanks.

Comment: if you are doing this to avoid needing root access, have you looked at [virtualenv](https://crate.io/packages/virtualenv/)?

Comment: I will be installing virtualenvwrapper - but, pardon my ignorance, what has that got to do with the pip install paths? So, Id want pip installed system wide and then use virtualenvwrapper - if this makes sense.

Comment: well, I was assuming you tried to install python packages without needing root access. That is what virtualenv is for. You create virtual environments (e.g. per project you are working on) and just install packages without `--install-scripts` and `--install-lib` because the default will be "local to this virtual environment". It's extremely useful if you have insufficient rights or need different versions of the same package.